# How do you get rid of Duplicate Chrome Aplication on Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Whenever I run Selenium, it creates a duplicate Chrome tab on my Mac Doc (the navigation panel). For example, if I run a basic selenium script like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pathlib import Path
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

#  Hide Pop-Up Window
WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
```

I get a duplicated Chrome tab on my Doc like:

[image: Duplicate chrome tab on Mac Doc]

Is there any way to remove this pop-up from happening?
Thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Selenium—the same thing happens with incognito windows and floating DevTools windows on other operating systems. It isn't a programming question, and is therefore off-topic here.

Comment: You might just want to add a command at the end of your script to close the window when it's done.